# Error with a theme when switching from visual basic express to visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, themes, basic

I have a project in visual basic that works perfectly fine on visual basic express 2010. Today, When I installed visual studio and opened the same project, and it can't display the main program (form1). Is showed that some class from designer needs to be to the top. I have changed that class in the theme but still I am unable to view my program. If I click `ignore and continue` I see just a blank form (as it would be a new project), from what I discovered is that visual studio simple fails to install the theme. Basically if a make any new project with visual basic express and put add the file containing the theme I can add the new buttons from the theme from the toolbox, in visual studio they won't appear hence the error as it can`t understand the buttons from form1

Here is the theme http://pastebin.com/gC9zJdkY

I would greatly appreciate if you could tell me why visual basic from visual studio can`t install the theme where the same project opened in visual basic express 2010 works perfectly fine, I want to move my work to visual studio and these is keeping me from work